# How to point cmake at specific directory for library?

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake project where I am using a library and now I want to test my code with a different version of that library. I can set INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES (and possibly later also linking) in the below example. But because I only want to do this temporarily, I'd like to manually set this path with ccmake/cmake-gui.

How do I do this?

```
project(min_example)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
# Without the following line please:
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/home/me/src/opencv/install/include")
add_executable(min_example main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(min_example ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This should be possible by setting the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable upon configuring your build. In your project directory generate a `test_build` directory and run:

```
mkdir test_build
cd test_build
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/me/src/opencv/install ..
```

Setting the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable will make the `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)` command pick your OpenCV installation in `/home/me/src/opencv` and set the `OpenCV_LIBS` and `OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR` variables accordingly.

Alternatively you can edit a `CMakeCache.txt` file of an existing build directory with the CMake GUI editor and add the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` definition there. You have to re-configure your project then.

Comment: It doesn't work. find_package(OpenCV) still picks up the libs+include in /usr/local/... I used your three lines as given above. Any idea what else I could try?

Comment: @Unapiedra Set the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to the directory in you home that contains the OpenCVConfig.cmake file (probably `/home/me/src/opencv/install`).

Comment: Thanks. It's actually `.../install/share/OpenCV` but that does it!

Comment: how do you list more than one directory on the cmake_prefix_path?

Comment: @AndrewHundt set it to a CMake list, i.e. `cmake -D "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/a/b/;/c/d"`

Comment: I had to use `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795816/hinting-findname-cmake-files-with-a-custom-directory.

Answer (score 1):

Using config in find_package will restrict search path to OpenCV_DIR. This will use the cmake config that opencv generates at build time to setup paths to include and libs

```
set(OpenCV_DIR "<cusompath>" CACHE PATH '' ${SHOULD_FORCE_CACHE})
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED CONFIG)
```

Comment: Both methods appear to work but isn't the xxx_DIR variable actually intended to just be used for internal?