# Hinting Find<name>.cmake Files with a custom directory

Tags: cmake

In CMake, is there a way to make built-in Find scripts to prioritize a custom directory that we specify? Because especially in windows, module finding scripts usually can't detect the module in, for example visual studio directories. Therefore I usually have to manually set the paths for the external libraries which is pretty tiring. Instead, I want those scripts to look in a custom directory, let's say 'dependencies' folder in the main project first so that I can directly put those externals in that folder which is much easier than putting them into the VC folder or manually setting the paths.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Setting [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html#variable:CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH) variable serves exactly these purposes: hinting `find_*` function about location of searched item.

While description of this variable doesn't note about `find_package` function, the variable affects it *indirectly*: the most of `Find<name>.cmake` scripts use [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html) and [find_path](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_path.html) functions. Note, that all `find_*` functions have *precise algorithm* for search items, and paths constructed with `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` are checked before system ones.

Moreover, `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` affects some other search procedures. E.g., if 3rd party package provides `<name>Config.cmake` script instead of `Find<name>.cmake` one, this script is also searched for using this variable. [pkg_check_modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPkgConfig.html) also uses `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to search for `.pc` files describing the package.

`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable can be set as environment one (in platform-depending and usage-specific way), as parameter to `cmake` call:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=<additional-path> <other-parameters>
```

or within `CMakeLists.txt` file. In the last case it is better to *append* search directories, so user of you package is able to set the variable too for search packages not shipped with your project:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies")
```

---

Note, that variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` doesn't affect searching for `FindXXX.cmake` script itself. For specifying the directory where the script is located, use `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable.

Comment: Thanks, it worked great. It's strange that such an important option is not noted to help Find scripts. Does it have any side effects that would "break" any script?

Comment: Until directory, listed in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, has some partial or broken installation, or has unrelated files under standard search suffixes (lib/, lib64/, include/, etc.), setting this variable shoudn't harm any `find` script. And if it does, this is a problem in the `find` script itself. The worst thing which could happen is that script may ignore directory listed in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. In that case one should check concrete `find` script.

Comment: I would add, that for **only** searching `Find<name>.cmake` you should use `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` instead...

Comment: I would like to add, for more information about `Find<name>.cmake` scripts, I would recommend reading the [find-modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#find-modules) page in the cmake manual.