# FindCURL doesn't support using CURL_ROOT variable

Tags: curl, cmake

When I used GTest library on CMake, I could use `GTEST_ROOT` for finding root path of GTest. However, I cannot use `CURL_ROOT` to use curl, because FindCURL.cmake doesn't get the variable.

How can I do?

Comment: You may set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795816/hinting-findname-cmake-files-with-a-custom-directory).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you! I'll post answer that based on your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable. Also you may use semicolon(`;`) with multiple paths.

**On script:**

```
set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH C:/Libraries/gtest;C:/Libraries/curl)

find_package (GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories (${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
find_package (CURL REQUIRED)
include_directories (${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

**On console:**
`cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:/Libraries/gtest;C:/Libraries/curl`