# undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::mpi::exception'

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to compile some open source code and it gives me the following error shown above.

I guess it means that the code is acutally compiling but during linking it cannot find this `boost::mpi::exception` library.

However I installed `libboost-mpi-dev` and successfully compiled some toy examples of `boost::mpi` like this one for example:

```
#include <boost/mpi/environment.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/communicator.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace mpi = boost::mpi;
int main()
{
  mpi::environment env;
  mpi::communicator world;
  std::cout << "I am process " << world.rank() << " of " << world.size()
            << "." << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

For compilation of the open source code I'm using a `CMakeList.txt` file. 
I have a feeling that my `boost 1.54` (standard Ubuntu 14.04 version) **is not downward compatible** to `boost 1.49` which the authors specify as minimum requirement in their CMakeList.txt:

```
find_package(MPI)
if( MPI_FOUND )
    find_package(Boost 1.49 COMPONENTS mpi)
    if( Boost_MPI_FOUND )
        message(status "** MPI support enabled")
        message(status "** MPI Libraries: ${MPI_LIBRARIES}")

        ### When I uncomment the next line the Code actually compiles however only without MPI ####
        add_definitions(-DUSE_MPI)
    else ()
        message(status "** MPI library found but Boost MPI not available; MPI support disabled.")
    endif ()
endif ()
find_package(Boost 1.49 COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)

message(status "** Boost Include: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message(status "** Boost Libraries: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
message(status "** Boost Libraries: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
[...]
```

Unfortunately even compiling `boost 1.49` didn't help me, since the `CMakeList.txt` is constructed such that it only finds the globally installed `boost 1.54` instead of the locally installed `boost 1.49`, although I added the local path to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Has anyone an idea how to fix that problem?

PS: This was the complete error message that appeared during `make`:

```
CMakeFiles/ColorDenoising.dir/ColorDenoising.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTIN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_3mpi9exceptionEEE[_ZTIN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_3mpi9exceptionEEE]+0x18): undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::mpi::exception'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[2]: *** [Apps/ColorDenoising/ColorDenoising] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [Apps/ColorDenoising/CMakeFiles/ColorDenoising.dir/all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    Linking CXX executable MultiLabel
    [100%] Built target MultiLabel
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: I could tell you what the problem is, but since you didn't even post the code that failed to compile, I see little reason to aid you. You don't seem to have done any serious investigation of... anything.

Comment: Hmm. What do you mean? The complete source code? (impossible to post) The library is called regression tree fields (if that was the question)

Comment: You could always try narrowing it down a bit first. That's usually the first step of figuring out what a problem is.

Comment: Alright, as I said, I would guess the `undefined reference` error is due to a incompatibility between my newer boost version and the one that is required as minimum. 
So I think teaching `cmake` how to look for my local installation of boost 1.49 might solve the problem. But since I'm a novice in `cmake` I don't know how to change the CMakeList.txt` in that way...

Comment: Read documentation for [findBoost](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html) about hinting `find_package(Boost)` to custom installation. Or use [generic approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795816/hinting-findname-cmake-files-with-a-custom-directory/34797156#34797156). When show error build log for others, please, disable parallel make (`make -j1`): build log for parallel build usually is a mess.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. At least I could now compile the source code using `boost 1.49`. Unfortunately the error `boost::mpi::exception` remains. I guess it's rather a problem with mpi than with boost afterall...