# How to say to cmake where to find ICU binaries

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation, cmake, icu

I'm trying to generate `visual studio` project for [MeTA](https://github.com/meta-toolkit/meta) sources using cmake (tryied both shell and gui) tool. However at the current moment it's fails when trying to resolve ICU components, since building from sources not available on Windows, and it's not find binaries (even if they placed the same directory). CMake file for ICU is [there](https://github.com/meta-toolkit/meta-cmake/blob/master/FindOrBuildICU.cmake)

At the current moment it's fails with this error:

```
-- Searching for ICU 57.1
-- ICU not found; attempting to build it...
-- ICU building not supported on Windows.
CMake Error at deps/meta-cmake/FindOrBuildICU.cmake:49 (message):
     -- Please download the latest ICU binaries from http://site.icu-project.org/download
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:51 (FindOrBuildICU)
```

So my question is - how could I say for cmake where to get binaries and satisfy ICU requirements?

Comment: According to code, it uses `find_package(ICU)` for find ICU installation. So you need to check `FindICU.cmake` script for know about hinting it. E.g., [this one](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/cmake/FindICU.cmake) suggests to set `ICU_ROOT` variable. You may also try generic approach for hinting `Find*.cmake` scripts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795816/hinting-findname-cmake-files-with-a-custom-directory.