# Crosscompile OpenCV with FFMPEG support

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, cmake, arm

I am trying to cross compile opencv with ffmpeg support for an arm board with a buildroot based custom linux.  The host is an ubuntu PC.

I want static opencv libraries.

I have downloaded ffmpeg source and crosscompiled it with the following configuration

```
./configure \
--enable-cross-compile \
--cross-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabihf- \
--target-os=linux \
--arch=arm \
--disable-static \
--enable-shared \
--enable-nonfree \
--enable-ffmpeg \
--enable-gpl \
--enable-swscale \
--enable-pthreads \
--disable-yasm \
--disable-stripping \
--prefix=../build \
--extra-cflags=-I../build/include --extra-ldflags=-L../build/lib
```

The paths are all correct and ffmpeg is built successfully.  Then when I try to configure opencv with cmake-gui, I have to manually specify all paths.
But despite this, opencv configuration is unable to resolve FFMPEG correctly

I have attached the screen shot below

[image: CMAKE-GUI]

It cannot resolve ffmpeg versions.  I tried to ignore it and build but it fails with linker error

```
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_features2d.a
[ 49%] Built target opencv_features2d
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Instead of *manually* filling paths to all libraries, it is better to set `FFMPEG_DIR` *environment* variable to the directory where FFMPEG is installed (`<...>/other_libs/ffmpeg/build` in your case), so script `FindFFMPEG.cmake` will be able to detect package *by itself* and fill all needed variables. (Note, that not all variables describing the package are shown in CMake cache).

Comment: Thanks, will try and let you know tomorrow

Comment: I used the option ADD ENTRY in the cmake-gui and pointed it to that path.  But on clicking configure, it doesn't resolve anything.  All FFMPEG fields stay NO.
    `FFMPEG:                      NO
      codec:                     NO
      format:                    NO
      util:                      NO
      swscale:                   NO
      resample:                  NO
      gentoo-style:              YES`

Comment: I also set ffmpeg dir environment variable from a separate shell.  then restarted cmake-gui and on configure it doesn't detect ffmpeg. 

Did i build ffmpeg wrong?

Comment: Hm, there are different `FindFFMPEG.cmake` scripts, probably, OpenCV uses one without checking `FFMPEG_DIR`. You may try to set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable, as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795816/hinting-findname-cmake-files-with-a-custom-directory/34797156#34797156): such approach works in most cases.

Comment: I decided to install ffmpeg in /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf directory directly.  This helped cmake in detecting ffmpeg automatically but it still is unable to resolve the version.  I also used option --disable-pic but no luck.  I do get the warning after ffmpeg configure `arm-linux-gnueabihf-pkg-config not found, library detection may fail`