# Cmake searches for opencv library

Tags: opencv, cmake

I have installed Opencv-3.2 and I can see the bin and lib files

```
$ ls /share/apps/computer/opencv-3.2.0/built/bin/opencv_
opencv_annotation     opencv_createsamples  opencv_traincascade     opencv_version        opencv_visualisation
$ ls /share/apps/computer/opencv-3.2.0/built/lib/
libopencv_calib3d.so           libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2.0   libopencv_stitching.so.3.2
libopencv_calib3d.so.3.2       libopencv_imgproc.so           libopencv_stitching.so.3.2.0
libopencv_calib3d.so.3.2.0     libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2       libopencv_superres.so
libopencv_core.so              libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2.0     libopencv_superres.so.3.2
libopencv_core.so.3.2          libopencv_ml.so                libopencv_superres.so.3.2.0
libopencv_core.so.3.2.0        libopencv_ml.so.3.2            libopencv_videoio.so
libopencv_features2d.so        libopencv_ml.so.3.2.0          libopencv_videoio.so.3.2
libopencv_features2d.so.3.2    libopencv_objdetect.so         libopencv_videoio.so.3.2.0
libopencv_features2d.so.3.2.0  libopencv_objdetect.so.3.2     libopencv_video.so
libopencv_flann.so             libopencv_objdetect.so.3.2.0   libopencv_video.so.3.2
libopencv_flann.so.3.2         libopencv_photo.so             libopencv_video.so.3.2.0
libopencv_flann.so.3.2.0       libopencv_photo.so.3.2         libopencv_videostab.so
libopencv_highgui.so           libopencv_photo.so.3.2.0       libopencv_videostab.so.3.2
libopencv_highgui.so.3.2       libopencv_shape.so             libopencv_videostab.so.3.2.0
libopencv_highgui.so.3.2.0     libopencv_shape.so.3.2         pkgconfig/
libopencv_imgcodecs.so         libopencv_shape.so.3.2.0
libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2     libopencv_stitching.so
```

Now, according to the [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html), I wrote a simple program. Problem is that, `cmake` gets some errors and seems that it is not able to find the library.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
  of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If   "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

I don't know how to set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` or `OpenCV_DIR`. How can I fix that?

The content of CMakeLists.txt is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Comment: How have you installed OpenCV on your machine? and also attach the contents of your `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: I followed the instructions. http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

Comment: Try with this [link](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: I don't think my problem is related to python. I just want to know how can I apply the suggestions made by cmake.

Comment: The link contained installs OpeCV from source and the python part can be simply ignored.

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether you have `OpenCVConfig.cmake` script, which comes with your installation of OpenCV (that is, under install directory `/share/apps/computer/opencv-3.2.0/built/`).

If your installation of OpenCV **lacks** of `OpenCVConfig.cmake` script, you need to ship **your project** with script `FindOpenCV.cmake` (find and copy it from the net, almost any of them is suitable), and add directory with this script to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH <directory-with-find-script>)
```

Possible ways to hint CMake about your installation of OpenCV:

1. If you have `OpenCVConfig.cmake` script, set `OpenCV_DIR` variable to directory contained this script:

   ```
   cmake -DOpenCV_DIR=/share/apps/computer/opencv-3.2.0/built/<...>
   ```
2. Set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable to installation prefix of OpenCV:

   ```
   cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/share/apps/computer/opencv-3.2.0/built
   ```

   This works both with `OpenCVConfig.cmake` and with `FindOpenCV.cmake` scripts. See also that question: [Hinting Find<name>.cmake Files with a custom directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795816/hinting-findname-cmake-files-with-a-custom-directory/34797156#34797156).