# PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP binary path

Tags: cmake, protoc

How does PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP know where to pick up the protoc binary from?

I have compiled protobuf locally and would like to point my CMakeLists.txt to the installed binary ( myfolder/protobuf-install/bin/protoc ) and not the system binary ( /usr/bin/protoc )

Normally for Boost, I would just set the BOOST_ROOT to my installed folder and it will find all the include_directories, libraries, etc.

How should it be done for Protobuf. I dont see any prefix option in the FindProtobuf.cmake.

```
set( Protobuf_SRC_ROOT_FOLDER "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/myfolder/")
find_package(Protobuf MODULE REQUIRED)
```

The error is

```
file STRINGS file "/usr/include/google/protobuf/stubs/common.h" cannot be read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package)
```

Ofcourse, the above path is in myfolder/ and not in the system folder. But why is protobuf looking for includes in the system path, when I have explicitly declared the root path as myfolder/

Answer (score 0):

Module `FindProtobuf.cmake` has a nice [description](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/FindProtobuf.html) of how to hint it with various things. E.g., hinting with executable could be performed with setting *Protobuf_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE* variable:

> The following cache variables are also available to set or use:
>
> ...
>
> Protobuf_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE
>
> The protoc compiler

```
cmake -DProtobuf_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE=myfolder/protobuf-install/bin/protoc
```

Also, common *CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH* variable works well, see that question: [Hinting Find<name>.cmake Files with a custom directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795816/hinting-findname-cmake-files-with-a-custom-directory).

Comment: I have modfified the question a little bit. the source of the problem starts with the include folder and not the binary.

Comment: Neither of these does anything for my build.
set(Protobuf_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE ${grpc_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/protoc)

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake3/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:164 (message):
  Could NOT find Protobuf (missing: Protobuf_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE) (found
  version "3.13.0.0")

Comment: `Protobuf_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE` should be a **CACHE** variable: Either set it in the command line with `-D` option or set it in `CMakeLists.txt` with CACHE option (see [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/set.html#set-cache-entry)).