# include library to clion project

Tags: cmake, wxwidgets, clion

I'm trying to include wxWidgets library in my project.
I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04. You can get wxWidgets from the repository (already compiled) and just include it by modifying a cmake file (included in CLion). It works fine doing just that.

However, I need to modify the sources and this means that I have to compile the library myself.
I followed the instructions from this file: 
https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.1.0/docs/gtk/install.txt

Now Cmake can't find the library.
What may be missing?

EDIT:

The part of CMake regarding wxWidgets :

```
find_package(wxWidgets 3.1.0 COMPONENTS core base media REQUIRED)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
target_link_libraries(projectName ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
```

Error:

```
CMake Error at /home/usrName/Clion/clion-2017.2/bin/cmake/share/cmake-
3.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
Could NOT find wxWidgets: Found unsuitable version "3.0.2", but required is
at least "3.1.0" (found
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;-pthread;;;-lwx_gtk2u_core-3.0;-lwx_baseu-3.0;-
lwx_gtk2u_media-3.0)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/home/usrName/Clion/clion-2017.2/bin/cmake/share/cmake-
3.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:375 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
/home/usrName/Clion/clion-2017.2/bin/cmake/share/cmake-
3.8/Modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake:931 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
```

Comment: `Now Cmake can't find the library.` - Show **exact** CMake message about this.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I updated the question. The version I need is wxWidgets 3.1.0 not 3.0.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hinting Find<name>.cmake Files with a custom directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795816/hinting-findname-cmake-files-with-a-custom-directory)

Comment: You should probably set the wxWidgets_DIR property to the path of your compiled files before calling ```find_package```