# Is it possible to exclude a directory from all cmake?

Tags: makefile, cmake

Right now, I want to exclude my Anaconda distribution from being searched by any cmake or make files. Is that possible? If so, how should I do it?

Comment: Your Anaconda is installed in some default location or within the Path?

Comment: @usr1234567 it is installed in my Desktop as anaconda3 (a directory)

Comment: Desktop computer or the directory Desktop? By default, CMake does not search the latter.

Comment: @usr1234567 Desktop directory

Comment: I know no ways for "exclude", but you may specify directory which will be checked before default ones. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795816/hinting-findname-cmake-files-with-a-custom-directory/34797156).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Specifying the order doesn't help because the library that I am compiling will search the entire computer for a file before it searches the next one. My case is Intel MKL library in anaconda which I don't want to use. I want it to use OpenBLAS instead.

Comment: CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH doesn't work unless I specify that for all cmake file (fail when a cmakelist reads another cmakelist). I just want the anaconda to be excluded by every cmake files.

Comment: In comments you describe many things which are *not common* for "being searched by CMake", like `the library that I am compiling will search the entire computer for a file before it searches the next one.` or `cmakelist reads another cmakelist`. It would be better to add this information **into the question post**. Also, show the way how the project searches the library. According to the specifics, what it uses is not a plain `find_package()`