# CMake: Set zlib path

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to compile libzip on Windows using CMake to generate makefiles. Libzip needs zlib so I'm doing the following:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DZLIB_LIBRARY=../../../zlib-1.2.11 -DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=../../../zlib-1.2.11 ..
```

This doesn't work, however. I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138 (message):
Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Why is that? I have defined `ZLIB_LIBRARY` and `ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR` to point to the latest zlib.

I've also tried the following:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DZLIB_LIBRARY=../../../zlib-1.2.11 -DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=../../../zlib-1.2.11
```

When I run CMake like this, I get the following two warnings:

```
CMake Warning:
Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR
ZLIB_LIBRARY
```

In comparison to the first approach, however, build files are now written to my build directory. When running `nmake`, however, only zlib seems to get built. libzip itself isn't built at all.

I'm out of ideas here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/module/FindZLIB.html) suggests to use `ZLIB_ROOT` as a hint for CMake about zlib location. Alternatively, you [may use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795816/hinting-findname-cmake-files-with-a-custom-directory/34797156#34797156) *CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH* for the same purpose.

Comment: Setting `ZLIB_ROOT` yields the following error: CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138 (message):
  Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY) (found version "1.2.11")

Comment: That error means that it can find the headers, but not the library itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer my own question, using relative paths for `ZLIB_LIBRARY` and `ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR` was the problem. When using absolute paths, it works just fine. Furthermore, `ZLIB_LIBRARY` needs to point to the library itself. Here is my final build line which works:

```
cmake -DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=d:\mystuff\zlib-1.2.11 -DZLIB_LIBRARY=d:\mystuff\zlib-1.2.11\build\zlibstatic.lib -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
```