# Error 'Could NOT find OpenGL' during building OSB on Raspbian

Tags: linux, cmake, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Hi I am following the installation from this guide https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio/wiki/Install-Instructions#linux, and I am currently stuck at one of the last steps.

When I run the code `cmake -DUNIX_STRUCTURE=1 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..`
, I get the following error message:

```
-- OBS_VERSION: 20.0.1-85-ga76b919
-- Could NOT find OpenGL (missing:  OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find Libcurl (missing: CURL_LIB CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/Modules/FindLibcurl.cmake:64 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  deps/file-updater/CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)


CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
/home/pi/obs-studio/deps/glad/OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory /home/pi/obs-studio/deps/glad
/home/pi/obs-studio/deps/glad/X11_X11_INCLUDE_PATH
   used as include directory in directory /home/pi/obs-studio/deps/glad
OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "glad" in directory /home/pi/obs-studio/deps/glad
X11_X11_LIB (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "glad" in directory /home/pi/obs-studio/deps/glad

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/obs-studio/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I have already installed OpenGL as well. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you have OpenGL installed into non-system location, you need to hint CMake about this location. E.g. by setting *CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH* variable, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795816/hinting-findname-cmake-files-with-a-custom-directory/34797156#34797156).

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg -S /usr/include/GL/gl.h`?