# CMake: how to override the default path for CONFIG packages?

Tags: cmake, qt5

I know that if I want CMake to find my custom `FindBlabla.cmake` file I can put the path leading to it to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable. But what if have a `BlablaConfig.cmake` file and want to tell CMake where it's located. I know also I can set `-DBlabla_DIR=/path/to/BlablaConfig.cmake` flag and I'll get what I want. But what if I have several such config files? I would like to avoid setting `*_DIR` variables for each of them.

To be more concrete we can consider the example of Qt config files. If I have e.g. Gentoo and install qt5 from Portage then the config files will be put to `/usr/lib/cmake/Qt5*/Qt5*Config.cmake` and CMake will be able to find it by default. But if I build qt5 from sources and install it to `/usr/local/Qt-some.version` then I have to tell CMake where to find those config files since `/usr/local/Qt-some.version/lib/cmake/Qt5*/Qt5*.Config.cmake` files are not visible to CMake by default.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting *CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH* variable affects on all packages:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local/Qt-some.version")
...
find_package(Qt5) # This will firstly consult "/usr/local/Qt-some.version" path.
```

See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34797156/3440745) to related question about hinting to `FindXXX.cmake` scripts.