# Specify Location of Cmake Find[Package]

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to find a given package using a FindX.cmake file. Unfortunately, it seems like it continues to use one located at /A/FindX.cmake, rather than a different one at /B/FindX.cmake. Is there a way to specify the location of which Find[Package].cmake is used by find_package(X)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hinting Find<name>.cmake Files with a custom directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795816/hinting-findname-cmake-files-with-a-custom-directory)

Answer (score 1):

Simply add path `/B` to the beginning of the *CMAKE_MODULE_PATH* variable:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/B" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
```

Such way CMake will prefer `FindX.cmake` script from `/B` to scripts in other directories.