# Python and C++: How to use pybind11 with Cmakelists including GSL libraries

Tags: python, c++, cmake, pybind11

I want to be able to call my C++ code as a python package. To do this I am using `pybind11` with CMakelists (following this example https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example). My problem is that I have to include GSL libraries in the compilation of the code, and these need an explicit linker   `-lgsl` .

If I were just to compile and run the C++  without wrapping it with python, the following Cmakelists.txt file does the job

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")

project(myProject)


add_executable(
    myexecutable
    main.cpp
    function1.cpp
)

find_package(GSL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(myexecutable GSL::gsl GSL::gslcblas)
```

but when using `pybind11` the template I found doesn't allow the `add_executable` therefore  `target_link_libraries` doesn't work.

I have trie this

```
project(myProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES)   # See below (1)



# Set source directory
set(SOURCE_DIR "project")

# Tell CMake that headers are also in SOURCE_DIR
include_directories(${SOURCE_DIR})
set(SOURCES "${SOURCE_DIR}/functions.cpp")


# Generate Python module
add_subdirectory(lib/pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(namr ${SOURCES} "${SOURCE_DIR}/bindings.cpp")


FIND_PACKAGE(GSL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(GSL::gsl GSL::gslcblas)
```

but this produces errors in the building.

Any idea ?

Comment: I would love whoever downvoter to leave a comment. Its quite useless to downvote with no explanation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Function `pybind11_add_module` creates a library **target**, which can be used for link added module with other libraries:

```
pybind11_add_module(namr ${SOURCES} "${SOURCE_DIR}/bindings.cpp")
target_link_libraries(namr PUBLIC GSL::gsl GSL::gslcblas)
```

This is explicitely stated in [documentation](http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html#pybind11-add-module):

> This function behaves very much like CMake’s builtin `add_library` (in fact, it’s a wrapper function around that command). It will add a library target called `<name>` to be built from the listed source files. In addition, it will take care of all the Python-specific compiler and linker flags as well as the OS- and Python-version-specific file extension. The produced target `<name>` can be further manipulated with regular CMake commands.

Comment: Thank you so much I am new to Cmake and cant navigate the docs as I should. This is however now generating a new error which is beyond my  comprehension: `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:22 (target_link_libraries):  The keyword signature for target_link_libraries has already been used with the target "namr".  All uses of target_link_libraries with a target must be  either all-keyword or all-plain`

Comment: @Tsyvarev  How to use this if `gsl` is installed at a non-standard directory. For example. if gsl was installed in a directory, which is inside the directory where the `CMakeList.txt` file exists.

Comment: @ankit7540: You may hint `find_package` about location of the GSL by setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable. See that my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34797156/3440745