# cmake libclang with homebrew llvm on macos

Tags: macos, cmake, clang

I try to build cquery on macos with cquery with llvm(homebrew), but some lib cannot be found.

```
$ LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"  
  CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include" 
  cmake -DSYSTEM_CLANG=ON  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=$(which clang) -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=$(which clang++) .

-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 6.0.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Using system Clang
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Clang (missing: _libclang_LIBRARY _libclang_INCLUDE_DIR)
  (found suitable version "6.0.0", minimum required is "6.0.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/FindClang.cmake:93 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:91 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/vonfry/.local/src/cquery/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: "C" compiler is set with [CMAKE_C_COMPILER](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER.html) variable, not with *CMAKE_C_COMPILE* one. Also, "==" in setting this variable looks like a typo.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sorry, I have retry it, but the lib also cannot be found.

Comment: Where do you have "clang" **library** and **header files**? Under `/usr/local/opt/llvm`? If so, hint CMake about this directory with *CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH* variable, like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34797156/3440745. Environment variable *LDFLAGS* is just for linker flags, it doesn't help CMake itself to find things.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Success!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795816/hinting-findname-cmake-files-with-a-custom-directory/34797156#34797156), use `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` for `find_*` function.