# How can I include Leptonica library in Tesseract Library cmakelists.cmake

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi, visual-studio-2017, cross-compiling

I'm building Tesseract OCR for OpenCV for Raspberry Pi using VisualGDB and Visual Studio 2017.
I was able to build Leptonica library.

It is located here:
`D:\Projects\tesseract\leptonica`

The include files are located here `D:\Projects\tesseract\leptonica\src`
And the built .so library files are located here `D:\Projects\tesseract\leptonica\build`

I'm trying to add Leptonica Cmake files to Tesseract CMakelists.cmake

I'm reading the cmake tutorial found at https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-to-create-a-ProjectConfig.cmake-file
Unfortunately, its not a good tutorial but just an example, it doesn't explain the minimum lines I need to add another library.

Using the example, I tried adding

```
add_subdirectory(leptonica)
export(TARGETS leptonica FILE "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/leptonica/build/LeptonicaConfig.cmake")
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/leptonica/build/LeptonicaConfig.cmake)
include_directories(${Leptonica_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(tesseract ${Leptonica_LIBRARIES})
```

I'm getting errors: 
`A required package was not found`
`configure_file problem configuring file`

What do I do to include the leptonica library in the tesseract CmakeLists so I can build Tesseract Ocr?

Also, it was asking for `FindLeptonica.cmake` do I need to create this file? What do I put in it?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to write "Config" file for leptonica, if it already has the one? There is `cmake/LeptonicaConfig.cmake` file under installation prefix. If you have problem with building Tesseract Ocr, then describe exactly these problems. E.g. start with the exact error message.

Comment: In my case it's located in `build/LeptonicaConfig.cmake`                                      The errors I'm getting are: `Checking for module 'lept>=1.74'
  
CMake Error at C:/Users/dmponoma/AppData/Local/VisualGDB/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:436 (message):
  A required package was not found`

Comment: Location `build/LeptonicaConfig.cmake` is inside *build directory*. You need to **install** Leptonica for properly use it. After that, add installation directory to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34797156/3440745.