# How to help 'FindPkgConfig.cmake' to find a package?

Tags: cmake

I am trying to compile my project and my project is using `sqlcipher` package. `sqlcipher` is cloned and installed in a custom path and I exported this path through `$PATH` in the `~/.bashrc` file. After configuration if I type `sqlcipher` in the terminal its working fine, but when I try to `cmake` my project on the same terminal its giving

```
-- Checking for one of the modules 'sqlcipher'
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:578 (message):
  None of the required 'sqlcipher' found
```

I guess I have to provide this custom path to cmake for finding this package. How to provide custom path to cmake? Where I am doing the mistake?

Comment: You need to set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable, like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795816/hinting-findname-cmake-files-with-a-custom-directory/34797156#34797156.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/xyz/ -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/iam/git/LIB_ROOT/bin ..` but not working

Comment: @Tsyvarev After removing `bin` from the above path its working. thank you so much.

Comment: Variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` should contain **installation prefix**, not a `bin/` directory with a program. Also make sure that you have `.pc` file installed (under given installation prefix) - exactly this file is searched by `pkg-config` utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module [FindPkgConfig.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/FindPkgConfig.html) defines functions `pkg_check_modules()` and `pkg_search_module`, which use [pkg-config](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkg-config) utility for locate the package.

The utility itself takes hints for searching from `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` **environment** variable, which contains *colon*-separated (`:`) paths with `.pc` files:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/iam/git/LIB_ROOT/lib/pkgconfig:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}"
cmake <...>
```

But the CMake functions also take hints from `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable, which contains *semicolon*-separated (`;`) **install prefixes** of the packages. Both flows of variable are accepted, *environment* and *CMake* ones:

```
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/home/iam/git/LIB_ROOT;${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}"
cmake <...>
```

or

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:PATH=/home/iam/git/LIB_ROOT <...>
```

Approach with setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is a common way for hint CMake for search packages: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34797156/3440745.

Comment: Note: `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` works for pkg-config only if `cmake_minimum_required` is 3.1+ OR if you set `PKG_CONFIG_USE_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to true.