# Using protoc inside CMakeLists from a non-standard directory gives "cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" error

Tags: c, cmake, linker-errors, proto, protobuf-c

I have a C application using **CMake** to generate Makefiles on **Linux**. The application contains `.c` as well as [.proto](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto) files. Now I need to genearte `.pb-c.c` and `.pb-c.h` using [protoc command](https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c#synopsis) in the `CMakeLists.txt` so that when I do `cmake .` the cmake generates the corresponding .pb-c and .pb-h. The protoc is used as:

`execute_process(COMMAND bash -c "${PROTOC_PATH} --c_out=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ --proto_path=${PROTO_DIR}/ ${PROTO_DIR}/*.proto")`

The problem is that my protoc binary and related `.so` file is not in `/usr/bin and /usr/lib` or `/usr/local/bin and /usr/local/lib`. They are in a directory inside the project - `$HOME/project-name/dependencies/bin/protoc and $HOME/project-name/dependencies/lib/libprotobuf.so.12`

Due to this I am getting error - **error while loading shared libraries: libprotobuf.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

But if I give the command as

`execute_process(COMMAND bash -c "protoc--c_out=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ --proto_path=${PROTO_DIR}/ ${PROTO_DIR}/*.proto")` and run `cmake .` then it works fine as linker is able to get the `.so` file from `/usr/lib`

**Mentioned below is a part of my CMakeLists.txt file**

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-rpath=${PROTOC_LIB_PATH} -L${PROTOC_LIB_PATH} -lprotobuf")

set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-rpath=${PROTOC_LIB_PATH} -L${PROTOC_LIB_PATH} -lprotobuf")

execute_process(COMMAND bash -c "${PROTOC_PATH} --c_out=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ --proto_path=${PROTO_DIR}/ ${PROTO_DIR}/*.proto")
```

But it's not working due to aforementioned error.

Also for those who might say it's a duplicate I have looked into and tried the following SO questions:

[Turning on linker flags with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3544245/6407858)

[I don't understand -Wl,-rpath -Wl,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6562403/6407858)

[CMake link to external library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8774593/6407858)

[Does cmake have something like target_link_options?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25043458/6407858)

[CMAKE RPATH not working - could not find shared object file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30398238/6407858)

https://serverfault.com/q/279068/435497

[How to add linker flag for libraries with CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24532853/6407858)

https://serverfault.com/a/926072/435497

Comment: Just `protobuf_generate_cpp(...)` like [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake#L77).

Comment: @KamilCuk `protobuf_generate_cpp(...)` generate **c++** files but I require *c* and there seems to be no way to generate them without using **protoc**.

Comment: True. You have the [sources](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake#L227), you can try to modify them. Btw. instead of  `bash -c 'protoc arg'` just do `protoc arg`, no need for bash.

Comment: @KamilCuk I have tried without `bash-c` but for some reason cmake is not executing the command without any error and thus not generating the required `.c` file from `.proto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17151) link which has a script showing **how to create a PROTOBUF_GENERATE_C function** which can then be used to generate the `.pb-c` abd `.pb-h` files.

From the above script I got the idea to make use of [find_program](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_program.html) which is similar to [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html?highlight=find_library) in a way that it lets you pass the `PATHS/PATH` option so that CMake looks for the required program in the mentioned path.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have a special use case, you do not need to call protoc yourself. Let CMake do this for you.

Have a look at: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/module/FindProtobuf.html
and [Cmake : find protobuf package in custom directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651181/cmake-find-protobuf-package-in-custom-directory)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `you do not need to call protoc yourself. Let CMake do this for you.` was what led me to do a bit more searching and ultimately I came across `find_program` which is what I was looking for and have posted as answer related to same.