# Failing to use XercesC in a CMAKE project

Tags: c++, cmake, xerces, xerces-c

I'm trying to create a CMAKE project that links to xerces-c on Windows. Xerces-C was built with cmake and installed in a folder. This is the layout of the installation:

```
xercesc/3.2.2
  |
  |-bin
  |  |-xerces-c_3_2.dll
  |  |-xerces-c_3_2D.dll
  |  |-(many executables)
  |
  |-cmake
  |  |-XercesCConfig.cmake
  |  |-XercesCConfigInterna.cmale
  |  |-(other .cmake)
  |
  |-include
  |  |-xercesc
  |     |-dom
  |     |-framework
  |     |-internal
  |     |-parsers
  |     |-util
  |     |-(other folders)
  |
  |-lib
  |  |-xerces-c_3.lib
  |  |-xerces-c_3D.lib
  |
  |-share
     |-doc
        |-(documentation
```

This is my CMakeFile.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10.0)

project (myproject)

set (CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} ${XERCES_ROOT})
message (STATUS "CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH is ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH}")
find_package (XercesC REQUIRED)

set (CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
include_directories (${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/..)
include_directories (${XercesC_INCLUDE_DIR})

set (PROJECT_SRC
  Dummy.cpp
  )

add_library (${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${PROJECT_SRC})
```

`XERCES_ROOT` is a variable defined in my master CMakeLists.txt

```
set (XERCES_ROOT "" CACHE FILEPATH "Root directory of the Xerces-C installation")
```

I execute cmake with following command:

```
 cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=D:\lib\Boost\1.69.0\ -DXERCES_ROOT=d:\lib\xercesc\3.2.2\ -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ../
```

When I execute cmake, I print the content of `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH`:

```
-- CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH is D:/lib/xercesc/3.2.2
```

That's the correct location. I set this variable right before the `find_package(XercesC REQUIRED)` line.

But the package is not found. This is the error message:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Failed to find XercesC (missing: XercesC_LIBRARY XercesC_INCLUDE_DIR
  XercesC_VERSION)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindXercesC.cmake:98 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  src/myproject/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

What I'm doing wrong? What can I do in order to tell CMAKE where to find Xerces? Maybe `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` usage is wrong?

Comment: What does it say for the library `XercesC_LIBRARY`? (also known as, are you sure you seleted the same target, 32 or 64bits, for noth?)

Comment: What do you mean exactly? In the error message it says that's missing. And I've selected the right target (64 bit)

Comment: Why would it be missing as it's obviously there? What does the error log say (CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log)

Comment: `CMakeFiles\CMakeError.log` is not created. `CMakeFiles\CMakeOutput.log` is empty.

Comment: That's odd. Neither should be empty. Are you sure you looked at the proper location? There is an error, so it should be int he error log (never saw it not happening).

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: Given error is emitted by `message(FATAL_ERROR)` command, why do you think that `CMakeError.log` or `CMakeOutput.log` should contain a record about that error?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Because it failed finding XercesC libraries first. That should be int he error log, just as finding the include path should be there as well. The FATAL is due to the validation process after this step. So the FATAL is not the first error.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: I have never seen logging of `find_path` or `find_library` calls even if they failed.

Comment: I've just cleaned the build directory and perform the entire build again. It's the same. No CMakeErrors.log created. The CMakeOutput.log is too long to be posted here, but it does not contain any errors. just a bunch of Visual Studio project settings. Complete ouput is here https://pastebin.com/4m4p5hEW

Comment: OK, and nothing odd in the general log about this missing library?

Comment: Generally, in CMake projects INCLUDE_PATH is **not** a ROOT one and usually ends with `/include`. In your case include path should be `D:/lib/xercesc/3.2.2/include`. For find a library, you need to specify `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH` variable. Alternatively, you may specify (add) `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable: this variable affects on both library and headers searching and it contains exactly ROOT's of the packages.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks! Using `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` solved my problem. Can you write an aswer so I can accept it? Thanks to everyone for helping me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For hint CMake about the root of external packages, used in your project, one may hint that root in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=d:\lib\xercesc\3.2.2\ <other-options>
```

Such way, your `CMakeLists.txt` doesn't need to bother about these hints at all: it just uses `find_package()` and expect everything to work.

See also [that my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795816/hinting-findname-cmake-files-with-a-custom-directory/34797156#34797156) about other ways of using `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable and others features of that variable.