# Finding a local-directory library with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project called `myproject`, with a build directory `myhome/myproject/build`.

I have a library called `libmylibrary.so` that lives in `myhome/folder/lib` with headers in `myhome/folder/include`

Then I have a CMakeLists.txt in `myhome/myproject` which looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)                                                                                                                                                                       
project (myproject)
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")
add_executable(myproject ${SOURCES})

find_library(MYLIB mylibrary REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(myproject PRIVATE mylibrary)
```

I run `cmake ../` in the build directory, and then `make`, and I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmylibrary
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I simply do not understand how this is so difficult. What am I missing? I have tried what feels like every combination of random but extremely similarly named CMake directives, with no success (and no information about the reasons for success or failure, so it's literally just trial and error).

How can I tell [whatever thing needs to know] where my library is, so that CMake can find it, without it being hard-coded in the CMake script? Thanks.

Thanks

Comment: Side note: `REQUIRED` is a keyword for `find_package` call; it has *no sence* for [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/find_library.html) and other `find_*` commands. Also, your `find_library` call sets `MYLIB` **variable** to the location of the library. So, for link with the library you need to use `${MYLIB}`, not a plain `mylibrary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For hint CMake about library location, you may set [CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH.html) variable to the directory, which contains the needed library:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=myhome/folder/lib <other-cmake-arguments>
```

Alternatively, if your library is contained under `lib/` subdirectory, you may hint about upper directory with `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=myhome/folder/lib <other-cmake-arguments>
```

The latter way hints other `find_*` commands too, see that [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795816/hinting-findname-cmake-files-with-a-custom-directory/34797156#34797156) for more info.