# Linking Qt app with CMake and Visual Studio

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, cmake

I'm trying to build a simple test Qt app using CMake and Visual Studio 2019.

I'm basing my tests on this example: https://github.com/jasondegraw/Qt-CMake-HelloWorld

I opened the CMakeLists.txt file with Visual Studio. During build i get:

```
[7/7] cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\helloworld.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x86\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x86\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1422~1.279\bin\Hostx86\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\helloworld.dir\helloworld_autogen\mocs_compilation.cpp.obj CMakeFiles\helloworld.dir\main.cpp.obj CMakeFiles\helloworld.dir\mainwindow.cpp.obj CMakeFiles\helloworld.dir\helloworld_autogen\EWIEGA46WW\qrc_resources.cpp.obj  /out:helloworld.exe /implib:helloworld.lib /pdb:helloworld.pdb /version:0.0  /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:windows  D:\Program\Qt\5.13.1\mingw73_64\lib\libQt5Widgetsd.a D:\Program\Qt\5.13.1\mingw73_64\lib\libQt5Guid.a D:\Program\Qt\5.13.1\mingw73_64\lib\libQt5Cored.a D:\Program\Qt\5.13.1\mingw73_64\lib\libqtmaind.a kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
  FAILED: helloworld.exe 
  cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\helloworld.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x86\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x86\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1422~1.279\bin\Hostx86\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\helloworld.dir\helloworld_autogen\mocs_compilation.cpp.obj CMakeFiles\helloworld.dir\main.cpp.obj CMakeFiles\helloworld.dir\mainwindow.cpp.obj CMakeFiles\helloworld.dir\helloworld_autogen\EWIEGA46WW\qrc_resources.cpp.obj  /out:helloworld.exe /implib:helloworld.lib /pdb:helloworld.pdb /version:0.0  /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:windows  D:\Program\Qt\5.13.1\mingw73_64\lib\libQt5Widgetsd.a D:\Program\Qt\5.13.1\mingw73_64\lib\libQt5Guid.a D:\Program\Qt\5.13.1\mingw73_64\lib\libQt5Cored.a D:\Program\Qt\5.13.1\mingw73_64\lib\libqtmaind.a kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
  LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1422~1.279\bin\Hostx86\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\helloworld.dir\helloworld_autogen\mocs_compilation.cpp.obj CMakeFiles\helloworld.dir\main.cpp.obj CMakeFiles\helloworld.dir\mainwindow.cpp.obj CMakeFiles\helloworld.dir\helloworld_autogen\EWIEGA46WW\qrc_resources.cpp.obj /out:helloworld.exe /implib:helloworld.lib /pdb:helloworld.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:windows D:\Program\Qt\5.13.1\mingw73_64\lib\libQt5Widgetsd.a D:\Program\Qt\5.13.1\mingw73_64\lib\libQt5Guid.a D:\Program\Qt\5.13.1\mingw73_64\lib\libQt5Cored.a D:\Program\Qt\5.13.1\mingw73_64\lib\libqtmaind.a kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\helloworld.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\helloworld.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1120) with the following output:
D:\Download\mocs_compilation.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct QMetaObject * __cdecl QObjectData::dynamicMetaObject(void)const " (__imp_?dynamicMetaObject@QObjectData@@QEBAPEAUQMetaObject@@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl MainWindow::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@MainWindow@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
```

and a load more LNK2019 errors after. The only thing that is different is that I commented out the "-Wall" line in the CMakeLists.txt.

As far as I can tell, this example has all the required elements to be working.

The only thing I noted is that I installed Qt 5.13.1 msvc2017 and I'm running msvc2019 but a thread on the Qt forum pointed out that those two versions are binary compatible.

Any thoughts on this problem?

Update: as @Tsyvarev pointed out, when Visual Studio runs CMake, it uses the MinGW kit that is installed along the msvc one. Where can I tell Visual Studio which Qt kit is the correct one?

Comment: "The only thing I noted is that I installed Qt 5.13.1 **msvc2017**" - Eh? The link path `D:\Program\Qt\5.13.1\mingw73_64\lib\libQt5Widgetsd.a` suggests that you have QT built with **MinGW**, not with Visual Studio (aside `mingw` subdurectory there is a suffix `.a` of the library, but Visual Studio uses native Windows library's suffix, `.dll`). Actually, I find this funny (=strange) that CMake chooses `.a` library even if it works under Visual Studio. Probably, you have passed some additional options for CMake?

Comment: I have both the mingw and msvc kits installed. I naively assumed that Visual Studio would pick the msvc one :/ Where would I specify which Qt install to use? (Edit: I'm using right click "generate cmake cache" so I don't specify anything as far as I know)

Comment: Hm, if you have `QT_DIR` variable in the CMake cache, which is set to `D:\Program\Qt\5.13.1\mingw73_64`, then change this variable accordingly.

Comment: The entry is now called Qt5_DIR, I also edited entries looking like Qt5Widgets_DIR and others for the other modules. It now runs. But having to edit the cache for every new module and having to do it again when the cache gets cleared doesn't seem right. I'll update the question.

Comment: Instead of `*_DIR` variables you may set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable to proper path. But that should be done with **clean cache** (that is, before the first "Configure"). See more about that variable in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795816/hinting-findname-cmake-files-with-a-custom-directory/34797156#34797156) to the other question.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to set this variable in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Tsyvarev for pointing out the problem and fix.

To sum up what happened:

- When Visual Studio runs CMake it doesn't hint that it should use MSVC
- CMake ended up finding the MinGW kit installed on the system

To fix it in a (as far as I can tell) durable way:

- Right the CMakeList file and clear the CMake cache
- Right click the CMakeList file and select "CMake Settings"
- Then click on "Edit JSON" in the top right
- You can add CMake variables in the JSON

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "x64-Debug",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "configurationType": "Debug",
      "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x64_x64" ],
      "buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\build\\${name}",
      "installRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\install\\${name}",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
      "buildCommandArgs": "-v",
      "ctestCommandArgs": "",
      "variables": [
        {
          "name": "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH",
          "value": "D:\\Program\\Qt\\5.13.1\\msvc2017_64",
          "type": "STRING"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that this is the part that defines the variable:

```
    "variables": [
        {
          "name": "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH",
          "value": "D:\\Program\\Qt\\5.13.1\\msvc2017_64",
          "type": "STRING"
        }
      ]
```

You should update the value accordingly. The rest of the file is generated by Visual Studio.

- Generating the CMake cache should now use the correct kit

Thanks again to @Tsyvarev.