# Qt 5.12.2 + CMake 3.21.1 + Visual Studio 2019 / 2022: linker problems

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, cmake

I have a project in which cmake generation passes correctly. But, when I try to build I receive 2800+ error with LNK2001 or LNK2019 code: inresolved external symbol. Some examples:

```
C:\Projects\client\out\build\x32-Debug\worker.lib(worker.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: double __thiscall QRectF::left(void)const " (__imp_?left@QRectF@@QBENXZ) referenced in function "public: class QStringList __thiscall Worker::readData(struct MinImg const &)" (?readBarcodes@Worker@@QAE?AVQStringList@@ABUMinImg@@@Z)

C:\Projects\client\out\build\x32-Debug\worker.lib(worker.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: double __thiscall QRectF::top(void)const " (__imp_?top@QRectF@@QBENXZ) referenced in function "public: class QStringList __thiscall Worker::readData(struct MinImg const &)" (?readBarcodes@Worker@@QAE?AVQStringList@@ABUMinImg@@@Z)

C:\Projects\client\out\build\x32-Debug\worker.lib(worker.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: double __thiscall QRectF::width(void)const " (__imp_?width@QRectF@@QBENXZ) referenced in function "public: class QStringList __thiscall Worker::readData(struct MinImg const &)" (?readBarcodes@Worker@@QAE?AVQStringList@@ABUMinImg@@@Z)

C:\Projects\client\out\build\x32-Debug\worker.lib(worker.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: double __thiscall QRectF::height(void)const " (__imp_?height@QRectF@@QBENXZ) referenced in function "public: class QStringList __thiscall Worker::readData(struct MinImg const &)" (?readBarcodes@Worker@@QAE?AVQStringList@@ABUMinImg@@@Z)
```

The same applies to every class which is contained by Qt. In other words, compiler doesn't see Qt directory ('C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64'). Toolset is set to msvc2019_x86. I tried the decision from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57897644/linking-qt-app-with-cmake-and-visual-studio) and also tried to add

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\Qt\\5.15.2\\msvc2019_64\\")
```

to the root CMakeLists.txt file - nothing helps.

I tried both VS 2019 and 2022.

Comment: Looks like you are not linking to the QtCore library.  Should be done similar to this: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-index.html#building-with-cmake](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-index.html#building-with-cmake) You probably have to show your minimal CMakeLists.txt that reproduces the problem.

Comment: If you are building a 32 bit application why do you have a 64 bit version of Qt? Or is `msvc2019_64` a 32 bit with a bad name?

Comment: @drescherjm msvc2019_64 as I know is 32-bit compatible. Anyway, I tried to use msvc2019 too - with the same result

Comment: @drescherjm to the 1st comment: I cannot share the project cause it's not opensource, but there are several CMakeLists files in child folders, so there is a code like 'find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)' and 'find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)'. I tried both to add 'set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\Qt\\5.15.2\\msvc2019_64\\")' into the root cMakeLists file and to those CMakeLists files which uses Qt5* direclty as shown above. Without one of this two changes, CMake generation fails as expected

Comment: If you have Qt REQUIRED in your find_package then `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\Qt\\5.15.2\\msvc2019_64\\")'` is not the correct fix. If Qt was not found you should have had an error in the configure step of CMake.

Answer (score 0):

firstely tap this line in your CMD
`set QTDIR "C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\bin"`
secondely make this line in your cmakelistes.txt
`set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{QTDIR})`

Comment: This is the same, and doesn't help anyway