# How to instruct "find_package" to find a package installed in a user-specified location?

Tags: cmake

I installed a software package using CMake, on a customized location, with the command line below

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install
```

Now CMake can no more find the package with the `find_package`.  The error message suggests me to specify either CMAKE_MODULE_PATH or CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.

I tried to specify the installation path using

```
 cmake .. -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=../install
```

It did not work.  But the following worked:

```
 cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=../install
```

Question: In general, what would be the sound and reliable way to specify the path for "find_package" to work correctly for finding a  package installed to a user-specified location?

Comment: Have you checked [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795816/) and my answer for it?